# CNAME redirect to Wordpress blog not working

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress, cname-record, .htaccess

I have two domains hosting in two different servers: domain1.com & domain2.com

I would like to forward "**blog.domain1.com**" to "**blog2.domain2.com**" which is a Wordpress blog using CNAME redirect.

Before I installed Wordpress.

> blog.domain1.com (=redirect=>)
>   blog2.domain2.com/index.htm
>   (working fine)

The browser will keep the URL (**http://blog.domain1.com**) even the index.htm is on domain2.com server.

However, after I installed **Wordpress**, the browser will change the URL to (**http://blog2.domain2.com**)

This is my current setup:

On domain1.com DNS:

> **blog.domain1.com** CNAME redirect to
>   **domain2.com**

on **domain2.com** .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.domain1\.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blog2.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

on **blog2.domain2.com** .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /blog2/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /blog2/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**blog2.domain2.com** is installed under **domain2.com/blog2/**

All I want to do is keeping the URL (**blog.domain1.com**) unchanged for the whole Wordpress redirect.

Comment: CNAME is an alias of a domain, not redirection.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the .htaccess in blog.domain1.com will work. In your configuration, it will not never be hit. The easiest way is just remove your cname setting and keep your .htaccess in blog.domain1.com. You probably need to learn more on how DNS and Apache works.

Comment: Sorry, I mean you can put 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.domain1\.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blog2.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
in blog.domain1.com's .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Until you can fix rewrite rules you can use [Redirection](http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/redirection/) Wordpress plugin:
"Manage all your 301 redirects and monitor 404 errors"

Easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

In your domain2 .htaccess file
replace
R=301
with
R=302

That tells its a temporary redirection which will keep the url address.  But keep in mind, the url address will always be blog.domain1.com [even if you are reading a permalink post within domain2]

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. However, after I change it to R=302. The URL is always blog2.domain2.com (I want to keep it as blog.domain1.com even the post is hosted under domain2) Thanks!